# How to get full emails list from db using group_concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, group-concat

I am using the query below to fetch emails records from table.

but its not getting full email list from the table.

```
select group_concat(email) as email from table
$temp=$Db1->fetch_array($sql);
$elist['emails']=$temp[email];
```

It brings out only 50+- records , but i have 1400+ records in db for email.

Question:
How to get complete emails from the db using group_concat i.e. comma seperated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `GROUP_CONCAT()` has a maximum length of 1024 characters (by default), and you're hitting that limit. It's possible to raise that limit, but not indefinitely, so that's not a good solution.

You don't need `GROUP_CONCAT()` here, though. What you want to do is fetch one row for each email address, *i.e.*

```
SELECT email FROM table
...
while ($row = $db->fetch_array) {
    $emails[] = $row["email"];
}
```

Comment: agreed the use of GROUP_CONCAT() does not make a lot of senses here

Comment: @duskwuff I need emails sperated by commas, so that i can use them for sending emails.

Comment: `$x=implode(',',$emails);` or  `$emails.= ','. $row["email"];`

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the default length of **GROUP_CONCAT** function by running below query then you have run your query.

System variable: [**group_concat_max_len**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) AS email FROM TABLE;
```

You can reset its value globally or session wise. Update the length based on you usage.